# How to get the last SVN revision number from a given date?

Tags: bash, svn, sh

I need to obtain the first revision number after given date?

For example, I need to know which is the first SVN revision number for the project Apache Hadoop after 2011-11-29.

I tried the command

`svn log -r {2011-11-29} http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/`

but in this case, there are no commit on 2011-11-29.

How can I get the first commit of 2011-11-29 or if not exist, after this date?
And finally, how can I only get the revision date from the SVN log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Revisions in date period**

Try

```
svn log -r {2011-11-01}:{2011-11-30} ## revision between dates
```

or

```
svn log -r {2011-11-01}:Head ## revisions from 2011-11-01 to head
```

or

```
svn log -r {2011-11-01}:Head -l5 ## Top 5 revisions from 2011-11-01 to head
```

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.revision

**Get revision date from log**

Try

```
svn.exe log --xml
```

And parse `<logentry><date>` tags with bash